# Error : Possibly unhandled rejection still exist after update to AngularJS 1.6.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have upgrade angular to 1.6.1 and angular-ui-router to 0.4.2.

I still get this error :/

The solution in the app config : `$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);` is not clean :/

Anyone knows a better solution ?

this is my test code :

```
beforeEach(function() {
  inject(function ($injector) {
    getResulfFile = $injector.get('GetResultFile');
    httpMock = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $q = $injector.get('$q');
    deffered = $q.defer();
  }); 
});

it('test promise reject of getResultFile.getResult', function() {
    var message= "Not Found";

    httpMock.expectGET('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/' + id + '/results/' + rID).respond(500, message);
    getResulfFile.getResult(id, rID).then(function(resp) {

    }, function(resp) {
        responseStatus = resp.status;
        response = resp.data;
    });
    httpMock.flush();
    expect(responseStatus).not.toBe(200);
    expect(response).toBe('Not Found');
});
```